# jQuery removing '-' character from string

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I have a string "-123445". Is it possible to remove the '-' character from the string?

I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
$mylabel.text("-123456");
$mylabel.text().replace('-', '');
```

Answer (score 184, accepted):

```
$mylabel.text( $mylabel.text().replace('-', '') );
```

Since `text()` gets the value, and `text( "someValue" )` sets the value, you just place one inside the other.

Would be the equivalent of doing:

```
var newValue = $mylabel.text().replace('-', '');
$mylabel.text( newValue );
```

---

**EDIT:**

I hope I understood the question correctly. I'm assuming `$mylabel` is referencing a DOM element in a jQuery object, and the string is in the content of the element.

If the string is in some other variable not part of the DOM, then you would likely want to call the `.replace()` function against that variable *before* you insert it into the DOM.

Like this:

```
var someVariable = "-123456";
$mylabel.text( someVariable.replace('-', '') );
```

or a more verbose version:

```
var someVariable = "-123456";
someVariable = someVariable.replace('-', '');
$mylabel.text( someVariable );
```

Comment: yip $mylabel is referencing a DOM element. I've tried this and it works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just in case you want to remove all occurrences of a string, instead of just the first one, you can use: $mylabel.text().replace(/-/g, '');

Answer (score 12):

If you want to remove all `-` you can use:

```
.replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'),"")
```

Comment: If you're removing a full stop/period: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-dots-in-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: its replace all chars. big like :)

Answer (score 9):

```
$mylabel.text("-123456");
var string = $mylabel.text().replace('-', '');
```

if you have done it that way variable `string` now holds `"123456"`

you can also (i guess the better way) do this...

```
$mylabel.text("-123456");
$mylabel.text(function(i,v){
   return v.replace('-','');
});
```