# Jquery removing string but keeping structure

Tags: jquery, replace, blogs

I'm piggy backing off of [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950357/jquery-removing-character-from-string) that talks specifically about removing a string from inside an element. The code to do that is:

```
  $this.text( $this.text().replace("text to strip out", "") );
```

I've successfully stripped out the text "categories: "

FYI: This is a blog page with categories that are dynamically added. HTML structure before I strip out "categories: ":

```
<container>
   <div class="categories">
     "categories: "  //This is what I strip out with above code
     <a href = "...">Category Name</a> //This is a linked category name
   </div>
</container>
```

The problem is that when I remove "categories: " it is also stripping out the  and leaving me with an unlinked "Category Name"

After the jquery runs html looks like this:

```
 <container>
   <div class="categories">Category Name</div>
</container>
```

I need to keep the link active, as I want the ability for the user to click "Category Name" to stay.

Comment: Does the code you use for the replace include anything about the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a `textNode` you need to use `contents()` to retrieve them, then a combination of `filter()` and `remove()`, like this:

```
$('.categories')
    .contents()
    .filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; })
    .remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rSEXm/)

Note this will remove all direct child textNodes. If you want to filter by the text of the node, amend the `filter()` function accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, don't know if it's the best way, is to save the anchor element as a javascript variable. Then after you remove the stuff you want to remove, inject that anchor back in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
$("div.categories").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace("categories: ", ""));
});
```