# Replace all string occurrences

Tags: javascript

I want to replace all the occurrences of `[h2][/h2]` in a JavaScript string
For example, I have

```
var mystring = 'hii[h2][/h2]';
```

I want to get -> hii

so far I tried

```
mystring.replace(/[h2][\/h2]/g, "");
```

Comment: `[` is a special character, you'd need to escape it too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2390789/1529630), but here with brackets instead of dots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the square braces.

```js
var mystring = 'hii[h2][/h2]';
let string = mystring.replace(/\[h2\]\[\/h2\]/g, '');
console.log(string);
```

Comment: Error: unterminated regular expression literal
Source Code:
 `str = str.replace(/\[i\][\/i\]/g,'');`

Comment: @Sourav: You forgot to escape the 2nd open square brace.

Comment: @Sourav: You have to **escape** the `]` and `[`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming nothing between those tags, you need to escape the `[]` also.

```
mystring.replace(/\[h2]\[\/h2]/g, "");
```

Comment: Don't you have to escape the closing square brace?

Comment: Nope, only [ is reserved; if its escaped a subsequent ] is just a regular character

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
str.replace(/\[h2\]\[\/h2\]/g,"");
```

note that you have to escape [ and ] if they form part of the text you want to replace otherwise they are interpreted as "character class" markers.

If the [h2] and [/h2] could also appear separate, you could use this one:

```
str.replace(/\[\/?h2\]/g,"");
```