# removing dot symbol from a string

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace all points in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-points-in-a-string-in-javascript)

I am trying to remove '.'(dot) symbol from my string. and The code that Ive used is

```
checkedNew = checked.replace('.', "");
```

Bt when I try to alert the value of checkedNew, for example if the checkedNew has original value U.S. Marshal, the output that I get is US. Marshal, it will not remove the second dot in that string. How do remove all dot symbols?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Split the string on all the `.`'s and then join it again with empty spaces, like this:

```
checkedNew = checked.split('.').join("");
```

Comment: thanks!!! :) it wrked will this wrk with all other symbols like underscore, hyphen?

Comment: Yep, it'll work with any symbol you put in.

Comment: Clever, but what it does is not immediately obvious when the maintainer comes along to change it.

Comment: @Quentin: Neither is your solution if the maintainer isn't overly familiar with Regex. That's what comments are for. :) But I'm biased though, I'm one of those "Regex is evil!" guys.

Comment: I had to also convert the value to a string

`checkedNew = checked.toString().split('.').join('');`

Answer (score 67):

You need to perform a global replacement as, by default, `replace` only performs one replacement. In theory you can pass an instruction to be global as the third argument, but that has some compatibility issues. Use a regular expression instead.

```
checkedNew = checked.replace(/\./g, "");
```

Answer (score 24):

replace will only replace the first occurance. To get around this, use a regex with the global option turned on:

```
checked.replace(/\./g, '');
```