# How to remove the "." from a decimal figure with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS and trying to remove the full stop from the returned number, I've managed to work out removing the thousand separator but not sure how to add to also remove the full stop. Anyone have any ideas?

JS

```
var total = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);
total = parseFloat(Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
total = total.replace(/\,/g,'');
var newTotal = Shopify.formatMoney(total, '{{ shop.money_format }}');
```

Currently returns:

> 5977.00

But think I need to return it like

> 597700

So that the `Shopify(formatMoney)` function re-builds it.

Comment: add the line: total = total.replace(/\./g,'');

Comment: Yea i assumed that, should i just add that after the /\, one or can i add both in that previous one?

Comment: You can do both at the same time with total.replace(/\.|\,/g,''); Look up "regular expressions" for more info.

Comment: Ahh perfect, i just tried add with another one so the amount was passed to the formatMoney function in shopify and displayed correctly and just done the merged one and worked a treat! thanks mate, if you want to make an Answer i will mark it :) thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the line: 
`total = total.replace(/\./g,'');`

Or, remove both the comma and the period at once with:
`total = total.replace(/\.|\,/g,'');`

Look up 'regular expressions' for more info on how to create searches for specific patterns in text.

Comment: Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split & .join` like so:

```
total = total.split('.').join("");
```

Refer to this page here: [removing dot symbol from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584438/removing-dot-symbol-from-a-string)

You can also use

```
Math.round(total)
```

or

```
parseInt(total);
```