# javascript replace function only replaces the first occurance

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML=document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML.replace("'","%%");
```

The above statement replaces only the first occurrence of the single quote. Could it be because that I do a submit right after that, and that javascript doesn't wait for the previous statement to be completed before moving on to the next one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using regex `/g`

```
.replace(/'/g,"%%")
```

Change your code as below,

```
document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML = 
                  document.getElementById("Message")
                          .innerHTML
                          .replace(/'/g,"%%");
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace globally in javascript you need to add /g to the replacement string.

See this SO link [How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-points-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expression in replace.

```
document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML=document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML.replace(/'/g,"%%");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gzQC/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Global (g)` flag in the replace() parameters.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression and the `/g` (global) flag. This will replace all occurrences:

```
document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML=
    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML.replace(/'/g,"%%");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: [Handle W3Schools with care](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052158/alternative-to-w3schools-mozilla-developer-network)

Comment: @ADC Yeah, but it offered a short, ambiguous answer accompanied with zero explanation and really great SEO. Though, I guess I'm just adding to the page rank with my reference. O_o