# Replace spaces with unedrscores in entire string

Tags: javascript

I have tried replace space's with underscore's(`_`). Using bellow method's in java script

```
var stt="this is sample";

var stpp= stt.split(' ').join('_'); 
var stpp= stt.replace(' ','_');
```

but it will replace first space with underscore after that it will ignore all spaces.

results like

> this_is sample

so how to replace all spaces with ( _ ) in sting using java script.

any one can help me.

Comment: delete the second `var stpp ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript replace function only replaces the first occurance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605425/javascript-replace-function-only-replaces-the-first-occurance)

Answer (score 2):

Use `String#replace` with a regular expression using the global flag (`g`):

```
var stpp = stt.replace(/ /g, '_');
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
str.replace(new RegExp(" ","g"),"_")
```

Or this:

```
var newstring = mystring.split(' ').join('_');
```