# Replace all occurances in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I've searched through different websites showing me the way to replace strings in js. But actually its not working! Why?

The code I'm using:

```
var str = "This is html. This is another HTML";
str = str.replace('/html/gi','php');
```

**Output:** `This is html. This is another html`

Nothing is changing. Its Frustrating!

References I've used:

- [How to Replace All Occurrences of a String using Javascript Replace
  Function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/replace-all-occurrences-of-string-using-javascript-replace-function.aspx)
- [How to replace all points in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-points-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No quotes:

```
str = str.replace(/html/gi,'php');
```

The [**RegExp**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) object can be expressed in its literal format:

```
/I am an actual object in javascript/gi
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I didn't knew it is valid in js!!

Comment: @SukantaPaul Actually, the RegEx MUST be expressed unquoted... However you can write `replace` in string-format.

Comment: @Christoph, thanks for clearing that up. I was referencing `new RegExp()`. However, it wasn't clearly stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes to make it work. `//` is a regex and may not be quoted.

```
str = str.replace(/html/gi,'php');
```

Alternatively you could write:

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('html','gi'),'php');
```

The non standard conform method would be this (works only in some browsers, not recommended!)

```
str.replace("apples", "oranges", "gi");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote from your regular expression like so:

```
var str = "This is html. This is another HTML";
str = str.replace(/html/gi,'php');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replace(/html/, 'php');
```

you shouldn't put single or double quotes for the first parameter.

Comment: I know, I was referring to this specific case