# jquery find text and replace (all)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="id1">

   apple

   ball

   dogsss

   dogsssdogsss

   dogsssdogsssdogsss

</div>
```

How Do I change ALL `dogsss` to `dollsss` using jquery?

Here is a code, but how to determine the element?

```
$('#id1 how???').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('dog', 'doll')); 
});
```

Here is similar question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146648/jquery-find-text-and-replace`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace all occurances in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013474/replace-all-occurances-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `replace` will only remove first occurrence from the string. Use `regex` with replace to remove all occurrences. Use **global flag** i.e. `g` in the `regex` to replace all occurrences.

Change

```
$(this).text(text.replace('dog', 'doll'));
```

To

```
$(this).text(text.replace(/dog/g, 'doll'));
```

Also, you can use [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) with callback to update the `innerText` of element.

**Demo**

```js
$('#id1').text(function(i, oldText) {
  return oldText.replace(/dog/g, 'doll');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">

  apple ball dogsss dogsssdogsss dogsssdogsssdogsss

</div>
```

Comment: I think is $(this).text(text.replace(/dog/g, 'doll'));

Comment: It's nice when an answer explain thing too, rather than just give code that work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) with callback, and use regex with [`/g`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp) modifier

```js
$('#id1').text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/dog/g, 'doll'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">
   apple
   ball
   dogsss
   dogsss
   dogsss
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `replace()`, use `split()` and `join()`, which will replace all occurrences instead of just the first one:

```js
$('#id1').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.split("dog").join("doll")); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">

   apple

   ball

   dogsss

   dogsss

   dogsss

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the '/g' for global in your regular expression. Otherwise only the first match gets replaced.

```
$(this).text(text.replace(/dog/g, 'doll'));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it:

```js
$('#id1').text(function(index, oldText) {
  return oldText.replace(/dog/g, 'doll');
})

// or not use a function
// $('#id1').text($('#id1').text().replace(/dog/g, 'doll'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id1">

  apple ball dogsss dogsssdogsss dogsssdogsssdogsss

</div>
```