# URI Escaping n number of slashes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a replace for all "%2F" strings specifically for a search term. I have already run the search term through encudeURIComponent(search_term) and need to double escape ONLY the %2Fs.

If the search term is "ac/dc", I want the result to be: ac%252Fdc.

I can do this quickly like this:

```
search_term = encodeURIComponent(search_term);
search_term = search_term.replace("%2F", "%252F");
```

However, this doesn't work for ac//dc, which returns:

```
ac%252F%2Fdc
```

when what I want is:

```
ac%252F%252Fdc
```

I can solve this by running a replace like so...

```
search_term = search_term.replace("%2F%2F", "%252F%252F");
```

This isn't scalable. I'm wondering why doing the first replace isn't replacing both "%2F" strings.

Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace all points in a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-points-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: in the beginning you say you want the result to be "ac%252Fdc" and then you say "what I want is: ac%252F%252Fdc" - can you please clarify a bit?

Comment: Software Guy - please note that the search term changed between examples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the replace global, like this:

```
search_term = encodeURIComponent(search_term);
search_term = search_term.replace(new RegExp("%2F", 'g'), "%252F");
```

Hideous, I know, but it works.

---

Edit: As **Rob W** suggests, you're better off using a Regular expression literal to do this:

```
search_term = encodeURIComponent(search_term);
search_term = search_term.replace(/%2F/g, "%252F");
```

Comment: Use Regular expression literals instead of the RegExp constructor for constant regular expressions: `/%2F/g`.

Comment: Thanks - I'm new to regular expressions - looks like some reading is in order!!!. I'll accept as soon as I can