# How do I replace single quotes with double quotes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The following code replaces only one single quote:

```js
var a = "[{'column1':'value0','column2':'value1','column3':'value2'}]";
var b = a.replace("'", "\"");
console.log(b);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-points-in-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```js
var a = "[{'column1':'value0','column2':'value1','column3':'value2'}]";
var b = a.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(b);
```

Edit: Removed \ as there are useless here.

Comment: awesome, it works, although I don't understand what that 'g' is for.

Comment: It's a RegExp flag. [Read all about them.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: "g" flag mean that your perform a global search

Comment: No need for the \ escapes.

Comment: Yeah, the "\" is understandable for the regex (although not needed), but not for the second param string

Comment: A note, using the \ will help to keep syntax highlighting from breaking.

Answer (score 9):

Need to use regex for this:

```
var a = "[{'column1':'value0','column2':'value1','column3':'value2'}]";
var b = a.replace(/\'/g, "\"");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9b3K3/

Answer (score 5):

You can use a global qualifier (a trailing `g`) on a regular expression:

```
var b = a.replace(/'/g, '"');
```

Without the global qualifier, the regex (`/'/`) only matches the first instance of `'`.

Answer (score 5):

`replaceAll(search, replaceWith)` replaces ALL occurrences of `search` with `replaceWith`.

Then, make sure you have a string by wrapping one type of qoutes by different type:

```
 "a 'b' c".replaceAll("'", '"')
 // result: "a "b" c"
    
 "a 'b' c".replaceAll(`'`, `"`)
 // result: "a "b" c"
```

---

### More about replaceAll

**replaceAll** ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)): `replaceAll(search, replaceWith)`

It's actually the same as using `replace()` with a global regex(*), merely `replaceAll()` is a bit more readable in my view.

(*) Meaning it'll match all occurrences.

---

Example 1 - search with a string

```
const p = 'Please replace all 2020 occurrences with 2021. 2020. 2020.' 
   
console.log(p.replaceAll('2020', '2021'));
// Result: "Please replace all 2021 occurrences with 2021. 2021. 2021."
```

---

Example 2 - search with regex

```
const p = 'Please replace all 2020 occurrences with 2021. 2020. 2020.'    
const regex = /2020/gi


console.log(p.replaceAll(regex, '2021'));
// Result: "Please replace all 2021 occurrences with 2021. 2021. 2021."
```

Important(**!**) if you choose regex:

> when using a `regexp` you have to set the global ("g") flag;
> otherwise, it will throw a TypeError: "replaceAll must be called with
> a global RegExp".

---

You can also use a function as `replaceWith`

> In this case, the function will be invoked after the match has been
> performed. The function's result (return value) will be used as the
> replacement string.

Answer (score 3):

This looks suspiciously like bad JSON, so I suggest using actual array and object literals, then encoding the proper way:

```
var a = [{'column1':'value0','column2':'value1','column3':'value2'}];
var b = JSON.stringify(a);
```

Comment: I did that but it takes too long than replacing the string.

Comment: I could have created the JSON string in proper format in the first place, but I was having trouble storing it (as session) in a hidden field. I replaced all the double quote to single quote so it would get stored in the hidden field. Then on the client side I'm replacing it back to double quote. I would appreciate if there is a better solution for it

Answer (score 0):

Add the `g` modifier: 
`var b = a.replace(/'/g, '"');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RegExp with the global flag `g` and all quotes will replaced:

```
var b = a.replace(/'/g, '"');
```

Comment: You don't "just add the global flag `g`". You created a regular expression and set the global flag. Which, by, the way, replaces the wrong characters with the wrong character