# How to replace all the word Microsoft to Google without using RegEx

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code it replaces only one word at a time. I want it to replace all the words at once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Replace "Microsoft" with "google" in the paragraph below:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo">Please visit  Microsoft Microsoft Microsoft Microsoft!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var txt = str.replace("Microsoft","google");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>`enter code here`
</html>
```

Comment: Whenever I see `try it` I giggle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-dots-in-a-string-using-javascript This can be adapted to meet your needs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: @Mr.Alien Whats so funny about "Try it"?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr W3Schools code :) or Tutorial reference probably...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 function myFunction() {
 var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
 var temptext = str.split("Microsoft").join("google");
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = temptext ;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do it without using RegEx?

Comment: try this above code update