# How do i replace all dot in string to Underscore?

Tags: jquery

I have number like `4.1.1.1` replace with `4_1_1_1`

Please provide solution in jQuery.

Comment: *"Please provide solution in Jquery."* How 'bout you do a ***minimum*** amount of research? This is not a remotely hard question to find the answer to.

Comment: Why don't you search your question on google ? or try it on

Comment: The suggested questions, when writing the title of the question, would already give enough answers to exactly this question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-dots-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Comment: SO isn't a code factory where you make orders by specifying what you want coded and how you want it delivered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need help here from any library, this is just plain Javascript:

```js
var str = "4.1.1.1";
alert(str.replace(/\./g, '_'));
```

Read about [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method of the String prototype and also about regular expressions you can use with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var convertDotToDash = function(string) {
    return string.replace(/\./g,'_');
}
```

This is what @Solution mentioned. Just made it into a function