# String replace does not replace second instance of character

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a simple code right here that is supposed to take the periods out of a string and then split all the words into an array. The array part works fine, but using `.replace` on my string only removes the first period. Isn't it supposed to remove all instances of a period? The result I get in the console is:

> ["This", "is", "a", "test", "of", "the", "emergency", "broadcast", "system", "This", "is", "only", "a", "test."]

As you can see the last period is still there. Why is it not being removed by my string replace and how can I take all the periods out of the string?

Here is my code:

```
var the_string = "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system. This is only a test.";
var str_words = the_string.replace(".", "");
str_words = str_words.split(" ");
console.log(str_words);
```

Comment: Or maybe [How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2390789/1529630) was a better duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a regex with the `g` (global) flag.

```
var str_words = the_string.replace(/\./g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following by splitting the string then using a `map` to remove the period(s):

```js
var the_string = "This is a test of the emergency broadcast system. This is only a test.";
var str_word = the_string.split(" ").map(function(x){return x.replace(".", "")})
alert(JSON.stringify(str_word));
```