# How can I replace point with comma?

Tags: jquery, text, replace

I want to replace all points with comma:

```js
var text = "1.2";
var comma = text.replace(/./g, ",");
console.log(comma);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result I expect:

```
1,2
```

Comment: You have to escape the dot as this character has a special meaning in a regular expression: _"(The decimal point) matches any single character except the newline character"_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-dots-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a regular expression (`/./g`) to find characters to replace; however, the [period/dot (`.`) in regular expressions](https://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot) matches *any-and-all* characters (i.e it's a wildcard).  This is why your output happens to be a string of just commas.

To get the behavior you're looking for (global search and replace of all periods), you must instead escape the dot with a backslash:

```js
var text = "1.2.3";
var comma = text.replace(/\./g, ",");
console.log(comma); // => "1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `/./g` with this `"."`

```js
var text = "1.2";
var comma = text.replace(".", ",");
console.log(comma);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just wonder, why it is working the other way around: `text.replace(/,/g, ".")` If I want to replace comma with point

Comment: @Jarla See my comment and/or the duplicate

Comment: @Jarla . might have special meaning in regular expression.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand!

Comment: This is not the appropriate answer, because it looks like @Jarla's intent is to do a global search and replace (not just replace the first match). See my answer for why your original attempt did not work and what you can do to remedy that.

Comment: @Jarla That is correct. This will only replace the first dot it finds. If you have multiple dots in your string I suggest you use  (Ryan) answer or (Commercial Suicide) answer

Answer (score 1):

@Andam already answered about using `replace` method, and it's pretty cool 
 for your case, but just good to know, that sometimes you can see the combination of `split` and `join` methods, which can be used for the same case:

```js
var text = "1.2";
var comma = text.split(".").join(",");
console.log(comma);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

`split` method returns an array of pieces before and after the argument, passed to this method, so you can work with this array too, if needed. But as I already said, `replace` would be enough, if you just want to replace one character to another.