# Periods/ellipsis and string.replace not replacing them, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace, google-chrome-extension

**Not a duplicate**, I've already tried the possible solutions at:

[How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-dots-in-a-string-using-javascript)

I've having a JS issue with string.replace not replacing periods/ellipsis, maybe I'm just really tired but it's annoying the **** out of me. I'd appreciate any suggestions. This is in a chrome extension content script if that has any relevance.

I've tried variations of the below code and .split, other regex, etc. with no luck. All content of document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().trim().split(/\s+/); is from the Google homepage after searching for the keyword "google".

Relevant code:

```
var kwArr = document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().trim().split(/\s+/);

//remove empties, links, etc here...

//stupid period/ellipsis...
//begin loop(i)
kwArr[i] = $.trim(kwArr[i].replace(/\.+$/g, ''));
kwArr[i] = kwArr[i].replace('.', '');
kwArr[i] = kwArr[i].replace("\./g", "");
kwArr[i] = kwArr[i].replace('/\./g', '');
kwArr[i] = kwArr[i].replace('/\u2E7F\/g', '');
kwArr[i] = kwArr[i].replace('/\u2E7F\/g', '');
kwArr[i] = kwArr[i].trim().replace(/\.+/g, '');
kwArr[i] = kwArr[i].trim().replace(/\.{3}/g, '');
//end loop(i)
//end hacks
```

Array dump with frequency after running kwArr through replace, etc.:

[image: Stupid...]

Data from console.log(JSON.stringify(kwArr)):

https://gist.github.com/PlexXoniC/5084ff5fb69785f60bd043a205923601

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Some of the strings contain unicode ellipsis `\u2026`, there's even a middledot `\u00B7`. Also, you can split by `/[.\u2026\u00b7]*\s+/` to skip the loop (the last word will still need a replace).

Comment: @wOxxOm - perfect, thank you!

Split worked perfectly for combining everything into one.

`/[.\u2026\u00b7]*\s+/`