# How to get numbers from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a variable which it contains a telephone number in a sentence, to know it better  it is like this `"tel": "Tel: 01.78.99.93.06",` now I need to get just numbers and put in another variable the out put should be like this `var nom="0178999306"`.

How I can do it with jQuery and JavaScript?

Appreciate very much

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: with respect I did lots of research and none of them work fine for me. if some one know java script know the answer well. I do not think it needs more details for expert. but thank you very much for your time and I surely care @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Then please demonstrate your attempts at solving the problem using your research; explain where your attempts fail. How they fail. What you expected to happen and what happened instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest and the most robust method would be to remove all non-numerical values from the string which can be done using a simple regex:

```js
var tel = "Tel: 01.78.99.93.06";
var nom = tel.replace(/\D/g, '');
console.log(nom);
```

Comment: I found an answer  and it solved. but I accept the question while its much more complete . thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use replace. If your var is called telephone, then do:

```
telephone = telephone.replace(“.”,””).replace(“other unwanted strings”,””);
```

Comment: it works fine with some changes. thank you very much. with the help of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-dots-in-a-string-using-javascript

Comment: This approach can be simplified using regex to replace all non-numeric characters: `telephone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`

Comment: Also note that the double quotes you're using will cause syntax errors in JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you think the answer which I have accepted once also could cause syntax errors?