# Convert the string into an array, removing the + characters

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I wanted to convert strings into array by removing  "+" characters. It is getting converted only for 1st element and not for all. Help me to convert "+" as "," for all the elements.

```
let myString = 'jan + feb + mar + april ';

let change = myString.replace("+",",");
console.log(change);

let myArray = change.split(",");
console.log(myArray);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> jan , feb + mar + april
>
> Array [ "jan ", " feb + mar + april " ]

I also tried using below option it raised an error

```
let myString = 'jan + feb + mar + april ';

let change = myString.replace(/+/g,",");
console.log(change);
```

**OUTPUT**

> SyntaxError: nothing to repeat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all dots in a string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390789/how-to-replace-all-dots-in-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Just split on the characters you have.

```
let myArray = myString.split(" + ");
```

There's no need to do a substitution first.

(That said, `+` is a special character in a regular expression so you need to escape it with `\` if you did want to keep your current approach).